# Resize graphics to fit in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, picturebox

I need to draw a Fermat spiral in C#. I did it, but I want my drawing to be filled in PictureBox, no matter how big real size is.

```
  public void DrawSpiral(double delta, double numCycles, int oX, int oY, SpiralType spiralType, Color color, Graphics g)
  {
        double a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        Pen p = new Pen(color, 1);
        double prevX = oX;
        double prevY = oY;
        double X = oX;
        double Y = oY;
        double fi = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); 
        double radius = 0;

        while (fi <= (numCycles * 360))
        {
            fi += delta;
            if (spiralType == SpiralType.FermaPlus)
            {
                radius = a * Math.Sqrt(fi); 
            }
            else if (spiralType == SpiralType.FermaMinus)
            {
                radius = -a * Math.Sqrt(fi);
            }
            prevX = X;
            prevY = Y;
            X = (radius * Math.Cos(fi / 180 * Math.PI)) + oX;
            Y = (radius * Math.Sin(fi / 180 * Math.PI)) + oY;
            g.DrawLine(p, (float)prevX, (float)prevY, (float)X, (float)Y);
        }
    }

 private void DrawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        DrawSpiral(2, 5, 150, 150, SpiralType.FermaPlus, Color.Blue, g);
        DrawSpiral(2, 5, 150, 150, SpiralType.FermaMinus, Color.Red, g);
  }
```

So, what should I do to have my drawing to be full filled in the PictureBox.

Comment: Then why aren't you using the picture box's size as bounds for the drawing?

Comment: @DonBoitnott sorry, if I ask, but how exactly? (oX and oY) in drawSpiral are coordinates of the centre of the Form, by the way

Comment: when you draw on the picture box graphics, then coordinates will be relative to the top left corner of the picture box, not of the form. is the picturebox docked to fill the entire form? do you want to scale the drawing as the picture box resizes, or do you want to keep delta constant and add as many turns as necessary to fill the available diagonal (circumcircle)? the former is easy, the latter is a nice maths problem.

Comment: @dlatikay want to scale the drawing as the picture box resizes

Comment: _`Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();`_ Dead on arrival. Never use `CreateGraphics`! Use the `Paint` event for drawing. Use `graphics.TranslateTransform(w2, h2)`  with `int w2 = pbx.clientsize/2` etc..to center the drawing surface around the origin. Overdraw if you want.. Finally: Collect the coordinates and use DrawLines instead of DrawLine!

Comment: _want to scale the drawing as the picture box resizes_ Either add more coordinates/loops or use `ScaleTransform` on the `Graphics` object!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Change the signature of the `DrawSpiral` to include the `ClientSize`  of the `PictureBox` instead of some center coordinates:

```
public void DrawSpiral(double delta, double numCycles, int spiralType, 
                                                       Color color, Graphics g, Size sz)
```

Then calculate the center dynamically:

```
 int oX = sz.Width / 2;
 int oY = sz.Height / 2;
 double prevX = oX;
 double prevY = oY;
 double X = oX;
 double Y = oY;
```

Next calculate the factor `a` :

```
 a = sz.Width / 2 / Math.Sqrt( numCycles * 360);
```

Finally call the method **only** from the `Paint` event, passing out the valid `Graphics` object:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Size sz = pictureBox1.ClientSize;
    DrawSpiral(2, 5, SpiralType.FermaPlus, Color.Blue, g, sz);
    DrawSpiral(2, 5, SpiralType.FermaMinus, Color.Red, g, sz);
}
```

Upon resizing the `PictureBox` it will still fill the area with the same number of loops..:

[image]

A few notes:

- The quality and performance could be improved by first collecting the data in a  `List<Point> points`and then using `DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray())`
- I used just the `width` when I calculated the factor `a`. Use `Math.Min(sz.Width, sz.Height)` to always fit it into a non-square box!
- I left your offset calculation in place; but you could instead do a `g.TranslateTransform()`..
- The `PictureBox` will `Invalidate/Refresh` itself upon **resizing**. If you change any parameters do call `Invalidate` to pick them up!